# Looking for an iTunes now-playing notifier

Tags: windows, windows-vista, itunes, notifications

Do you know of any iTunes now-playing notifier for iTunes 8 on Windows? The only ones I've found are either for Mac (use AppleScript) or for iTunes 7. I just want to see the artist, title, album and album art when a new track is played.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to recommend [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx) with the iTunes plugin (can't post a second link at the moment).

Growl is a general notifier, that sits in your tray and produces pop-ups, based on events happening (change tracks, downloads finished, etc.). The pop-ups are a little like those windows messenger produces, but you can style them and make them and have different styles for different applications.

You can also get notifications for other apps, by installing plugins available from the growl website.

Comment: Wow, deliciously scriptable to satisfy my poweruser needs! Thanks a bunch for this :)

Comment: Yup its brilliant :-) ...

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.skinitunes.com/default.aspx) one I've found. Haven't actually used it, but it supports iTunes 8.

Comment: I ended up choosing Growl over this, but you still get an upvote for providing a valid answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [iTunesControl](http://itunescontrol.com/) for both its system-wide keyboard shortcuts as well as the customizable notification appearance.  It's free, and works with the current version of iTunes.  I've been using it for over two years now, with no adverse affects or whacky behavior. (Don't let the so-so screenshots fool you -- it's entirely possible and easy to make the notification simple and elegant!)